# Shall we implement both opcache and memcache?

Tags: performance, moodle

Shall we implement both `memcache` and `opcache` to increase the performance of the site developed in Moodle?

Answer (score 1):

You can use both.  OpCache and Memcache serve different purposes.  OpCache is a bytecode cache engine while Memcache is an in-memory data storage engine.

When a PHP script is compiled at runtime, it requires additional execution time compared to when OpCache is used (human readable code has to be converted for usage by the computer).  OpCache only compiles the script once (during the first execution) after which it keeps the pre-compiled script in memory leading to better performance.

Memcache allows you to store data in-memory (thereby avoiding some calls to a disk based database) leading to better performance.

Comment: Thanks for your response                                                                            I am facing problem in installing zend opcache extension in the windows server
Currently i am using PHP 5.4.12 version.Steps i have followed are summarized below.
 - Download the files from the below url
   http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/opcache/7.0.4/
   (php_opcache-7.0.4-5.4-nts-vc9-x86.zip) and copy the
   "php_opcache.dll" in to PHP extensions folder
 -items added in php.ini are
zend_extension = "realpath/ext/php_opcache.dll";
opcache.enable = 1
After that restart the apache

Comment: better to use a different question for that as it would help those specifically looking for that info.